# Uploading image using Selenium python not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What i am trying to is a basic functionality of selenium. Test scenario is click image Upload button select an image Then it will show the upload bar if uploaded successfully then click ok button. but this is not happening. No file is showing when i am uploading an image. it should it doesn't sending the file. I have attached the image for better view.
Here is my approach:

Button Option Html : `<input type="button" value="Click To Upload" id="upload-button" onclick="javascript: $('#file-upload').click();" xpath="1">`

My locator: `uploadInputBtn = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='upload-button']")`

My function to send the data :

```
def input_image(self):
    imageField = self.find_element(*self.locatorforImageUpload.uploadInputBtn)
    imageField.send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/photos/avatar.jpg")
```

[Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3A3.jpg)
it isn't doing anything/doesn't sending any file here. i am using MAC OS

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @cruisepandey no error is showing! that's the problem. It should include the image but it isn't doing anything

Comment: Please share that HTML in text format

Comment: I am getting `Not Found (#404)
This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff.`

Comment: Still the same issue, probably you use a different host to upload the file

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E1vRpd2x7_RMO-f7VOUD4ijabg3FOik8d8Lz9cAQ_4w/edit?usp=sharing Here is the googleDriveLINK

Comment: you'll want to send the absolute path to the file to the <input type="file"... element.  (not the button)